# ksh cannot cp from location with space in it?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I am trying to do the following in ksh but keep getting cannot stat message for the cp command:

```
 JMX_ROOT=/bfs-build/build-info/mep_mainline-Linux.latest/core/mainline/automation

 SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION=$JMX_ROOT/"Smoke Set"/*.*

 cp $SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION /var/tmp/tempor
```

Any ideas, have tried putting quotes around the various variables but with no luck. Think its something to do with the spaces in "Smoke Set" but don't how how to work it.

Many thanks.

Comment: also exists on [unix&linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23392/4667)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JMX_ROOT=/bfs-build/build-info/mep_mainline-Linux.latest/core/mainline/automation
SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION="$(echo $JMX_ROOT/"Smoke Set"/*.*)"
cp "$SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION" /var/tmp/tempor
```

Comment: Also, `*.*` should probably be changed to `*`. This is not DOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JMX_ROOT=/bfs-build/build-info/mep_mainline-Linux.latest/core/mainline/automation

  SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION=$JMX_ROOT/"Smoke\ Set"/*.*

  cp $SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION /var/tmp/tempor
```

Does this solve your problem?  Adding a `\` before the space.

Comment: Tried this but get:
cp: cannot stat `/bfs-build/build-info/mep_mainline-Linux.latest/core/mainline/automation/Smoke\\': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `Set/*.*': No such file or directory

Comment: Nope didnt work either, had to change it to the following: SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION=$JMX_ROOT/Smoke*/*.* I.e. replaced the space with a wildcard

Answer (score 0):

try escaping the space with a backslash

```
SMOKE_JMX_LOCATION=$JMX_ROOT/Smoke\ Set/*.*
```